# finding the first occurence in a list

Tags: ocaml, caml

I want to find the first occurence of a digit in a list :

```
let pos_list = function (list , x) -> 
   let rec pos = function 
    |([] , x , i) -> i
    |([y] , x , i) -> if y == x then i
    |(s::t , x , i) -> if s == x then i else pos(t , x , i + 1) in pos(list , x ,  0) ;;
```

but the compiler complain that the expression is a "uint" type , and was used instead with a "int" type .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second case from the pattern matching. This case is already matched by the last one with `s = y, t = []`. So the function can be simplified to

```ml
let pos_list (list, x) =
    let rec pos = function 
    | ([], x, i) -> i
    | (s::t, x, i) -> if s == x then i else pos(t, x, i + 1) in pos(list, x, 0) ;;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `==` (physical equality) instead `=` which is structural equality? I realize that this might not make a difference if you only have integers but it might yield unexpected behaviour down the road.

See the Comparisons section in the doc: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html

Answer (score 1):

Pavel Zaichenkov's answer is of course the best one, but you might be interested in knowing the exact cause of the error. Namely, when you have

```
if y == x then i
```

without a corresponding `else` expression, the whole expression is treated as

```
if y == x then i else ()
```

where `()` is the only value of the type `unit` (and not `uint`), which is the type of expressions that are evaluated for their side effects only. Since both branches of the `if` must have the same type, `i` is deemed to have type `unit` also. Then, when type-checking the third branch of the pattern-matching, you try to add `i` and `1`, which means that `i` should have type `int`, hence the type error.